# How to set navigation large title

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, wix-react-native-navigation

Can we set react native large title text for ios/iPhoneX/iPhoneXR? 
It should hide when scrolled. Is there any default navigation style or options is there in react-native?

We can create that manually but I would like to know is there any default props is there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you taking about collapsing tool bar layout

Comment: @user7747472 You can see here sample: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwip67S89PfiAhUbT30KHRqyBXgQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F48039046%2Fios-11-large-title-navigation-bar-snaps-instead-of-smooth-transition&psig=AOvVaw0CRt16SNhI6V_PBbEaad8f&ust=1561114936511149

Comment: That's collapsing toolbar, and as far as I know wix react native navigation v2 does not have that option by default.

Comment: However if you are using V1 then you can check this one , which might be helpful 
 https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1318